# Associative Cache in multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, concurrency

I'm trying to implement a version of N-way associative cache in assumption that it can be used by multiple threads. The data structure is pretty straightforward - a high level class to represent a set of cache lines and data structure to represent an individual cache line (I will omit unnecessary details):

```
public static class SetAssociativeCache<TKey, TValue> {
    
    private final int setCount;
    private final List<CacheSet<TKey, TValue>> sets;
    private final AtomicInteger itemsCount;

    ...

    public void set(TKey key, TValue value) {
    ...
    }

    public TValue get(TKey key) {
    ...
    }

    public void addOneItem() {
        itemsCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void deleteOneItem() {
        itemsCount.decrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itemsCount.get();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class CacheSet<TKey, TValue> {
    private final int capacity;
    private final List<CacheItem<TKey, TValue>> store;
    private final LinkedList<Integer> usageTracker;
    private final ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    
    ...
    public void set(TKey key, TValue value) {
    ...
    addOneItem();
    ...
    }

    public TValue get(TKey key) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I would like to have following features in the implementation:

- On a set operation, only cache line that corresponds to instead key is locked
- The same for a get operation - only one cache line is blocked
- And I also would like to have a total number of elements in the cache

Currently, I did manage to achieve it via ReentrantReadWriteLock on a cache set level (CacheSet) and an AtomicInteger variable that has a total number of elements in cache, on a cache level (SetAssociativeCache). On every insert, I call either addOneItem or deleteOneItem (on cache eviction). Even though the approach seems to work, I don't really like the fact that cache set has a link back to the parent class.

I think the better idea is to store the items count on a CacheSet level (CacheSet) and execute aggregation function on a Cache (SetAssociativeCache) level, but I can't think of any way to implement it without completely blocking set operations on all cache sets.

Could you please advise if there is a better or more elegant way to implement a behavior that I've explained above?

Comment: I've got soo many questions: 1) Why does a `Set` hold keys AND values? In Java terms, that would be a `Map`, not a `Set`. 2) Why do you have a `List<Set<>>`? Would access to the individual `Set<>` not be much faster via another `Map<Set<>>`? 3) Why would you need blocking a 'line' for read operations? 4) Your problem to the approach with the counting is that it is not guaranteed that `addOneItem()` actually does add an item. Usually 'add' methods return a boolean or TValue so you can actually see in the caller what hapened. Why not have a `countItems()` method, that iterates over all children?

Comment: 5) Closely related to (1): Why would you have a `List<CacheItem<TKey, TValue>> store`? This whole thing seems at least one, probably two levels too complicated for what we see in the code. A simple association (TKey=>TValue) getting pushed through 2 classes with 2 lists and its own wrapper, the big unknown `CacheItem`... At the moment I only see an overengineered failed design. Please show more of the code so we can understand how things are really intended. Creation and usage? 6) What do you mean by 'cache line`? Your first two bullet points are already solved with `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Comment: @ JayC667 thank you for your reply, I'll try to post the whole code shorty. In mean time, let me try to address some of your questions: 1) May be I've choose quite misleading name, but it's not related to Set data structure, but the container to hold the cached objects. 2) There is no way to create fixed size map, thus I've created an immutable list that I can use mod to calculate to which set inserted key belongs (something like Math.floorMod(key.hashCode(), setCount)). Answer to 3) is that another thread can insert a value during the counting process, thus returned value won't be accurate.

Comment: Noted regarding 4); I think I did cover 5) in my answer to question 2). The cache line is quite a widely used, e.g. there are quite a few mention of it in wikipedia's post about cache (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache). In my example, it's a synonymous to cache set.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, that's correct, the first two bullet points are solved via ReentrantLock, so I'm seeking an advice on how to implement count function in a better way.

Comment: regarding (2): `Math.floorMod(key.hashCode(), setCount)` will probably create collisions at some point, unless you really really take care of that yourself. Why does it have to be immutable? Same reason as for the block-on-read? If even COUNTING has to be thread-safe, the count result also has to be locked in with follow-up operations, so you'd have to block access to ALL the data in `SetAssociativeCache` while you interact, thus destroying the advantages of line-wise locking, thus you could move the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` to `SetAssociativeCache` and delegate to a `Map`..

Comment: What I want to say: you cannot combine line-wise locking with "thread-safe" counting over all lines, when the lines have multiple items. And to make matters worse: if you really need thread-safe counting, you probably also need to access the data in the same state, so 1) lock whole 'Map', 2) count 3) check items in the Map 4) release lock. Thus, by simply stating that "global" counting (as opposed to counting in one line) has to be thread-safe, you have to be able to lock ALL data.

Comment: The only alternative I could give you then is that you use true immutability through all 3 levels (SetAssociativeCache + CacheSet + CacheItem), which means that for every change, you have to create deep copies, and that might be really bad if your cache changes frequently.

Comment: @JayC667 thank you for your thoughts! I'm considering to offer a reward for the question, thus other opinions / solutions might be posted.

Comment: One notable thing with CPU caches is that they are automatically coherent and updated at a line level.  That is, modifications to any item in a cache line cause notification and update transactions for the entire line.  If you lookup the term `false sharing` you can find some discussion of this.   Your cache does not appear to handle notification, which means if I get() an item, and later set() that item, I might overwrite an earlier set(), leaving an inconsistency.